# TinyMCE4 custom self closing tag

Tags: tinymce-4, tinymce-plugins

I have some custom XML tags which I want to use in my TinyMCE 4 editor.
One of it, is self closing.
For example this 'html' is valid:

```
<include type="module" name="MyModule">
    <param name="myParam" value="myValue" />
</include>
```

According to allow these custom tags, i've added the following things to my init:

```
extended_valid_elements: "include[type|name],param[type|name|value]",
valid_children: "+p[include], +include[param]",
```

After inserting the code snippet, TinyMCE converts it into:

```
<include type="module" name="MyModule">
    <param name="myParam" value="myValue">
</include>
```

Now the param tag isn't closed anymore.

After searching, I found the variable *self_closing_elements*. Adding my custom tags to it, unfortunately didn't work. I also 'played' with *short_ended_elements* and *whitespace_elements*, without any success.

So, how can I allow these custom tags to be self closing in TinyMCE 4 (I can find allow about version 3, not about v4...).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was a bug in the version I used. After updating to the latest TinyMCE4 version, it worked like a charm